# Check if user_signed_in before run the special def in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

For example I have defs: `def index`, `def manage`, `def new`. And in routes I have the next:

```
if user_signed_in?
    def new
    end
end
```

But when I wrote it other def(index and manage) also asks me login. How can I do that just new def asks me login?

routes:

```
get "/new" => "posts#new"
```

Comment: Your question is clutter. Put parts of your real controller, and your real config/routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line to the controller instead

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed using Devise please skim the guide in its entirety.[The filters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) are what you missed.

`before_filter :authenticate_user!` is the way to go.

What you are doing in your question is conditionally defining the controller's actions based on a boolean of whether a user is signed in/not, which is, in essence, a wrong approach. Besides, at the point of definition of the controller class, there isn't a user.